# Map is not visible in leaflet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, maps, leaflet

Not able to display Map on leaflet ! I have tried this

mymap.js

```
.controller('MapCtrl',function () {
var map = L.map('map1', {
  center: [52.48626, -1.89042],
  zoom: 14
});
```

index.html

```
<div  ng-controller="MapCtrl"> 
<div id="map1"></div>
```

I got this Error **map container is already initialized** and **map container not found** But tried to modify the code as

```
(function initController () {
var map = L.map('map1', {
  center: [52.48626, -1.89042],
  zoom: 14
});
map.remove();}) ();
```

I didn't get any errors, But Still Map is not Visible !!

Comment: can u give us a sample plunker with your data and have looks on given examples here http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/basic/first-example

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/EC9FcRWQcwfQhbjly1Yr?p=preview

Comment: your leaflet cdn's not loaded in your plunker check in console.....check for the same in application